# Basic authentication using spring security in corda

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, corda

I am trying to add basic authentication for api's in Corda using spring security. 
The cordapp was running perfectly before integrating spring security. 
After integration, it is throwing one or the other error.

If only a spring boot template is run no errors are thrown. I believe the error is in the nodeRPCConnection file.

This is the error that's getting thrown.

```
W 12:51:44 1 AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh - Exception 
encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'inMemoryUserDetailsManager' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
: Failed to instantiate 
[org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager]: Factory method 
'inMemoryUserDetailsManager' threw exception; nested exception
is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(Ljava/lang/String;)
Lorg/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User$UserBuilder;

I 12:51:44 1 AnnotationMBeanExporter.destroy - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
W 12:51:44 1 CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction - Invocation of 
destroy method failed on bean with name 'nodeRPCConnection': kotlin.UninitializedP
ropertyAccessException: lateinit property rpcConnection has not been initialized
I 12:51:44 1 StandardService.log - Stopping service [Tomcat]
I 12:51:44 1 ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.logAutoConfigurationReport -
```

#### BasicAuthConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
open class BasicAuthConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    }

    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password("{noop}root")
            .roles("ADMIN")
   }

}
```

#### NodeRPCConnection

```
@Component
open class NodeRPCConnection(
        @Value("\${$CORDA_NODE_HOST}") private val host: String,
        @Value("\${$CORDA_USER_NAME}") private val username: String,
        @Value("\${$CORDA_USER_PASSWORD}") private val password: String,
        @Value("\${$CORDA_RPC_PORT}") private val rpcPort: Int): AutoCloseable {

    lateinit var rpcConnection: CordaRPCConnection
        private set
    lateinit var proxy: CordaRPCOps
        private set

    @PostConstruct
    fun initialiseNodeRPCConnection() {
            val rpcAddress = NetworkHostAndPort(host, rpcPort)
            val rpcClient = CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress)
            val rpcConnection = rpcClient.start(username, password)
            proxy = rpcConnection.proxy
    }

    @PreDestroy
    override fun close() {
        rpcConnection.notifyServerAndClose()
    }
}
```

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` likely points to issues in your dependencies. You may want to share your pom.xml or build.gradle so someone can help you with the issue pointed at from your logs.

Answer (score 0):

This is something where you'd want to be sure of your dependencies as steve said.

Take a look at these dependencies in the corda samples:

- https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/secretsanta-cordapp/clients/build.gradle#L19